# Get data from API key to save into database

Tags: json, codeigniter, api

I am working on website app, made with Codeigniter. I want to fetch data from API key and save them into database. I have a base code, but it is not working. And which files all do I need? I am new at this and have a lot of difficulties with that task.

**Controller:**

```
public function ee_cron_job(){

  $decode_data = $this->Campaign_model->get_ee_api();
  $this->db->query($query);
  foreach ($decode_data->result() as $current) {
    $data = array(
          'ee_name' => $current['Name'],
          'ee_clicked' => $current['Clickedcount'],
          'ee_open' => $current['Openedcount'] ,
          'ee_recipient' => $current['Recipientcount'],
          'ee_sent' => $current['Sentcount'],
          'ee_failed' => $current['Failedcount'],
          'ee_unsubscribe' => $current['Unsubscribedcount'],
          'ee_dateedded' => $current['Dateadded'],
          'ee_lastactive' => $current['Lastactivity']
    );
  $this->db->query($query);
  $this->Campaign_model->add($data);
  $this->db->update('ee_campaigns');

 }
}
```

**Model:**

```
public function get_ee_api() {

  $response = Requests::get("https://api.elasticemail.com/v2/campaign/list?apikey=*", array());
  $this->get_ee_api();
  return json_decode($response->body, true);

}


public function get_data(){

  $query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM ee_campaigns');
  foreach ($query->result() as $row)
    {

      echo $row->ee_name . '<br/>' ;
    }
}
```

First, the error was:
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 5085070 
Than I added ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M'); and the second error occurred:
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 120 seconds exceeded.

What should I do to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you have put your model in a never ending loop.

```
public function get_ee_api() {

  $response = Requests::get("https://api.elasticemail.com/v2/campaign/list?apikey=*", array());
  //$this->get_ee_api(); take this line off. The function is calling it self over and over.
  return json_decode($response->body, true);

}
```

This should take you out of your execution time issue and hopefully the memory issue as well.

And if you need to follow MVC pattern you need to stop doing DB operations in your controller.
Get the model to do the query and pass the result back to the controller.
Loop that result and I don't see a query variable in your controller either.

-- Trying with curl

```
public function get_ee_api() {
    $response = $this->get_web_page("https://api.elasticemail.com/v2/campaign/list?apikey=*");
    $resArr = array();
    $resArr = json_decode($response);
    echo "<pre>"; print_r($resArr); echo "</pre>";

    //return json_decode($resArr); remove comments if you get proper output

    }


    private function get_web_page($url) {
       $options = array(
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,   // return web page
            CURLOPT_HEADER         => false,  // don't return headers
            CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,   // follow redirects
            CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 10,     // stop after 10 redirects
            CURLOPT_ENCODING       => "",     // handle compressed
            CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => "test", // name of client
            CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER    => true,   // set referrer on redirect
            CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120,    // time-out on connect
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 120,    // time-out on response
        ); 

        $ch = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);

        $content  = curl_exec($ch);

        curl_close($ch);

        return $content;
    }
```

Comment: I get this error: A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Array to string conversion

Filename: admin/campaigns.php        for this row in view:<?php echo $this->Campaign_model->get_ee_api(); ?>

Comment: Make sure you are referring to the proper element in the array. It looks like the DB is getting an array instead of a string. try using print_r($response); or on the line number php is telling you

Comment: It looks like something is wrong wit request in model: $response = Requests::get("https://api.elasticemail.com/v2/campaign/list?apikey=**", array());

Comment: Can you simply type the api url on the browser and see if you are getting any result?

Comment: I have added curl section in to the model to retrieve the data. can you try that see if you are getting the required response ?

Comment: You are most welcome. Can you accept my answer please